# How to localize filename encoding in LG WebOS smartshare and linux console?

Tags: linux, encoding

I have a samba server with my films library, all the filenames are in Russian literals. I want to use my samba server in my TV LG WebOS Smartshare app, so I could watch movies right from my tv, without connection external player, such as android box. The only way I found is a trick with mounting this samba resource to the removable usb drive with CIFS (using usb drive because it is visible in smarthshare application as a device).

Also I needed root access to my TV OS. I have already done it.

So right now, I have an access to my films library. But here is the problem. All my filenames of the films are in Russian language. And in smartshare application all the name are displayed as "?????", "????????" - question marks, which makes impossible to navigate and just choose the film I want to watch. And if i try to go into folder named "????" i get error "Unstable connection". But if I go into folder names "Cartoons", it works just fine.

In my console, connected via telnet to the tv, I can see the whole Linux filesystem. And there is the same problem, while trying to ls the films folder.

telnet ls films directory

Usually, people just use locales and environment variables LANG and LC_ALL. But I dont have an utility locale in my WebOS linux system. Also there is no package manager available, but opkg. But it seems like developers from LG disabled any ability to install new packages.

I have wget and curl and internet connection.

My OS (got with command cat /proc/version):

Linux version 3.10.19-32.afro.6 (gatekeeper.tvsw@ubuntu-1204) (gcc version 4.6.4 20120731 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG 1.15.3 - 2013.08_nc4) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 28 03:44:13 UTC 2019

I suppose this problem to be a linux system localization., but don't know how to fix it.

So how do I get my russian symbols start working?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the thing was in mounting with cifs. I had to set one important option **iocharset=utf8**. This solved the thing. I was surprised that utf8 is not set by default.